# What is total possible no of subsets of a set with given n elements and max subset length possible is k

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, dynamic-programming

For Example let's say the given set is $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ i.e $n=4$ elements 
and I have to find the subsets possible till the maximum length of $k=2$.

To do this i've to do All possible combinations of subsets from length $0$ to length $k =2$ which causes time limit exceeded to my problem .

Since the calculation of total no of subsets i.e till the maximum length of set possible is much easier to find using $2^n$ which takes only $\log n$ time asymptotically

So my Question is.. Can we find this for $k$  in $\log(n)$ time which would be something like $2^n$ or in exponential form ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Are you looking for the number of subsets or do you wish to generate the subsets? If it's the latter, then for $k=n$ there are $2^n$ subsets. I don't see how these could be generated in less than $2^n$ operations.

Comment: Yes i want the total number:) not the later

Comment: The number of subsets is $$N = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom {n}{i}$$ Are you asking if there is a faster way to compute this than simply adding the $k$ terms?

Comment: @Jens Yes i was asking that